# Display Custom Attribute Of Simple Product Within A Configurable Product

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-attribute, configurable-product-options

When selecting product options within a configurable product I want to show some custom attributes of the simple product.

I have created a dropdown attribute called "my_delivery_method" with Two values "Parcel Delivery" and "Pallet Delivery"

I have set up two products;

- a small product, with "Parcel delivery"
- a large product with "Pallet Delivery"

These are now part of a configurable product. I want to display this attribute under the header (which I have done) but I cannot make them change depending on the option selected. e.g. when someone chooses the small item refresh to show "parcel delivery"

Can someone explain how to make custom attributes for a simple product display depending on the option within a configurable product that is selected?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have found and used a tutorial to do something similair. It is about displaying and changing the sku but i think you can do the same with your problem.

[Here is the tutorial](https://magecomp.com/blog/switch-product-sku-according-selection-child-products-magento-2/)